# How to mock this method using EasyMock and PowerMock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock, easymock

I have a method like this:

```
public Object method() {
  Object1 object1 = new Object1();
  return object2.someMethod(object1);
}
```

Now my assumption to mock this is:

```
public void methodTest() {
  Object1 object1 = EasyMock.createMock(Object1.class);
  PowerMock.expectNew(Object1.class).andReturn(object1);

  Object2 result = new Object2();
  EasyMock.expect(object.someMethod(object1)).andReturn(result);
  EasyMockHelper.replayMocksFor(this);
  result = myTestClass.method();
  EasyMockHelper.verifyMocksFor(this);
}
```

I'm getting an error where the the expect method is not matching up with what is being called. It expects that an EasyMock class of object1 is being passed to object.someMethod() but is getting a non mocked class of object1.

Hope that makes sense and thank you in advance for the help.

Adding some semi real code:

```
public Object1 methodToTest(Object2 someParameter) {
    Object3 object3 = new Object3();
    object3.setSomeMethod(EnumObject1.FOO);
    return object4.getSometMethod(object5, someParameter, EnumObject2.BAR, object3).getSomeMethod(); 
}
```

object4 and object5 are both auto wired in the class.

Comment: Do not mix PowerMock and EasyMock

Comment: is the above code correct? how are you getting the `object2` in `method` and `object` in `methodTest()`?

Comment: object2 is autowired and object is a instance variable in the class that is being mocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
EasyMock.expect(object.someMethod(EasyMock.isA(Object1.class)).andReturn(result);
```

This will mock any Object of type `Object1`. So it will work for you.

In that case you won't need to use below code:

> Object1 object1 = EasyMock.createMock(Object1.class);
>   PowerMock.expectNew(Object1.class).andReturn(object1);

Comment: So my object.someMethod() actually takes 2 parameters, one is Object1.class and another is a mocked object and I'm getting an IllegalStateException saying 2 matchers expected, 1 recorded.  If I turn both of the parameters into matchers, then I get an Unexpected method call exception where the parameters don't match up to the actual method call.

Comment: Dude it's working for me. Please check once more, might you have missed something. Or please insert your whole test code.

Comment: Adding some obfuscated code that reflects the logic